# Throwing an exception if resque is not enabled

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resque

I currently have a rails app that sends tasks to a resque queue. In the rails app, a progress bar gives a "percent done" reading via ajax polling. This all works perfectly well...unless resque is down, in which case the progress bar just sits at zero forever, with no notification to the user that the task isn't going to run (at least, not until someone starts up a resque worker).

My question is: Is there any way to bubble an exception back to the rails app if resque isn't actually up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK I dont thing such functionality exist in resque not atleast in `v1-x-stable` I believe,

but `Resque` has few handy method which can help eventually

1. `Resque::Worker.all`     => Return List of `all` workers present
2. `Resque::Worker.working`    => Return List of `currently running  workers`

### Case 1 :

Now if your queue is `*` (GLOBAL QUEUE)  then I believe

checking the above

`Resque::Worker.all.empty?`  or `Resque::Worker.length == 0` or `Resque::Worker.present?`

would do the trick for you

### Case 2

Now if you dont have `*` (GLOBAL QUEUE) Perhaps then you need to hooks some of your codes to achieve that (lets assume your queue name is `progress_bar`)

`Resque::Worker.all.map { |worker| worker worker.to_s.split(':') =~ /(\*|progress_bar)/ }.present?`

#### NOTE:

I'm checking for `*` **GLOBAL QUEUE** as well as `progress_bar` QUEUE and also I'm not sure whether the regex is broken or not you can check that on your end I believe

### Last TIP:

At any given time Redis is the awesome source of information if you want metadata about Resque worker or job Just .

Hope this help